# PHP To Create Table In ECHO Statement

Tags: php, sql-server, echo

I am attempting to echo my results to an HTML table.  I am close with my syntax, but instead of one table header and 3 rows returned, I get 3 table headers and the same 3 rows returned under each header.

This is what I get returned:

```
Name    UserID    LogonID
Joe     j12       je12
Joe     j12       je12
Joe     j12       je12
Name    UserID    LogonID
Bob     b23       bb23
Bob     b23       bb23
Bob     b23       bb23
Name    UserID    LogonID
Sam     s99       sm99
Sam     s99       sm99
Sam     s99       sm99
```

This is what I want returned:

```
Name   UserID   LogonID
Joe    j12      je12
Bob    b23      bb23
Sam    s99      sm99
```

What do I need to change in my php file in order to get my desired results?

```
$SQL = "SELECT TOP 3 [Name], [UserID], [LogonID] FROM [employeeinfo] ORDER BY ID ASC";

$result = mssql_query($SQL) 
    or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '  <th>Name </th>';
    echo '  <th>User ID </th>';
    echo '  <th>Logon ID </th>';
    echo '</tr>';  
          foreach($Row as $r) {
              echo '<tr><td>' . $Row['Name'] . '</td><td>' . $Row['UserID'] . '</td><td>' . $Row['LogonID'] . '</td></tr>';
          }
    echo '</table>';
```

Comment: you're using `as $r` but not using it and creating a new table for each in the loop

Comment: Looping inside loop, instead of 3 iterations you square them - 3^2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using two loops remove one and your code will be like this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT TOP 3 [Name], [UserID], [LogonID] FROM [employeeinfo] ORDER BY ID ASC";

$result = mssql_query($SQL) or die('A error occured: ');
$number_of_rows = mssql_num_rows($result);
 if($number_of_rows > 0) {
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '  <th>Name </th>';
    echo '  <th>User ID </th>';
    echo '  <th>Logon ID </th>';
    echo '</tr>';  

while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   echo '<tr><td>' . $Row['Name'] . '</td><td>' . $Row['UserID'] . '</td><td>' . $Row['LogonID'] . '</td></tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
}
```

> **Note:** Don't use mssql function as it is deprecated. Use the mysqli or PDO.
>   [Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php)

Comment: @justbaron yes I checked that. That's why use mysql function uniformly. Thanks for point out in comment. Other can also view that.

Comment: @justbaron *"The OP has a mixture of both mssql() and mysql()"* - Huh? There's no `mysql_` in their code.

Comment: now he deleted his comment. Code Lover... the OP is using this on an sql-server; why rewrite with a totally different api?

Comment: plus what you posted for their query in brackets, is purely mssql/oracle syntax `[COL]`, not mysql

Comment: @Fred-ii- Frankly I don't know what function he is using. but here he has wrong logic also and wrong function name.

Comment: When I use this, nothing is echo

Comment: *"Don't use mysql function as it is deprecated"* - there is no mysql, it's mssql.

Comment: @Fred-ii- -- I see, I think it is due to using mysql number of rows function.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for showing right thing to me. OP has already tag with sql server. that I have not noticed. now I have made changes in the answer.

Comment: Glad to see everything's been ironed out ;-)

Comment: @CodeLღver We all learn from each other, that's one of the beauties of this forum ;-) most welcome.

Comment: This really helped me... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your "echoing" of the table and header needs to be outside of your loop if you want only one occurrence, you could simply do this in HTML. Also I don't understand why you do a second loop (foreach) in your while loop as you don't even use the $r variable and use the $Row variable already defined by the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You did not understand the fetch thing I think, you should do something like :

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '  <th>Name </th>';
echo '  <th>User ID </th>';
echo '  <th>Logon ID </th>';
echo '</tr>';  
while ($Row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $Row['Name'] . '</td><td>' . $Row['UserID'] . '</td><td>' . $Row['LogonID'] . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```